# выбивает ошибку при установке друпал

Tags: drupal

Выбивает ошибку при установке друпал на локальный сервер на моменте "Установка базы данных".
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in W:\domains\Site\drupal-9.0.7\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Database\Statement.php on line 59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну по идее в ошибке все описано. Замените в файле php.ini вашего локального сервера `max_execution_time = 60` на `max_execution_time = 600` и перезапустите сервер.